# http always call error function

Tags: angularjs

This is my snippet of code. Seems that everything is ok, but I don't know why, I always get en error2 alert. URL is 100% working and it returns array of string in unicode

```
App.service('categoriesService', function($http) {
    this.getData = function(callbackFunc) {
       return $http.get('http://yuppi.com.ua/rest/categories.php?key=453sdfg3t').error(function(data) { alert("error2");});
      }
});

[{"id":3,"name":"\u042d\u043b\u0435\u043a\u0442\u0440\u043e\u043d\u0438\u043a\u0430","count":"4265"},{"id":6,"name":"\u041a\u043e\u043c\u043f\u044c\u044e\u0442\u0435\u0440\u044b \u0438 \u041d\u043e\u0443\u0442\u0431\u0443\u043a\u0438","count":"6424"},{"id":11,"name":"\u0422\u0435\u043b\u0435\u0444\u043e\u043d\u044b \u0438 \u041f\u043b\u0430\u043d\u0448\u0435\u0442\u044b","count":"4882"},{"id":5,"name":"\u0414\u043e\u043c \u0438 \u0441\u0430\u0434","count":"8008"},{"id":4,"name":"\u0424\u043e\u0442\u043e \u0438 \u0412\u0438\u0434\u0435\u043e","count":"7434"},{"id":2,"name":"\u0422\u0440\u0430\u043d\u0441\u043f\u043e\u0440\u0442","count":"7440"},{"id":10,"name":"\u041d\u0435\u0434\u0432\u0438\u0436\u0438\u043c\u043e\u0441\u0442\u044c","count":"1891"},{"id":7,"name":"\u041c\u0443\u0437\u044b\u043a\u0430\u043b\u044c\u043d\u044b\u0435 \u0438\u043d\u0441\u0442\u0440\u0443\u043c\u0435\u043d\u0442\u044b","count":"6653"},{"id":8,"name":"\u0425\u043e\u0431\u0438, \u043e\u0442\u0434\u044b\u0445 \u0438 \u0441\u043f\u043e\u0440\u0442","count":"3597"},{"id":9,"name":"\u0422\u043e\u0432\u0430\u0440\u044b \u0434\u043b\u044f \u0434\u0435\u0442\u0435\u0439","count":"7417"},{"id":12,"name":"\u0416\u0438\u0432\u043e\u0442\u043d\u044b\u0435","count":"3775"},{"id":13,"name":"\u041c\u043e\u0434\u0430 \u0438 \u0441\u0442\u0438\u043b\u044c","count":"5816"},{"id":14,"name":"\u0420\u0435\u043c\u043e\u043d\u0442 \u0438 \u0441\u0442\u0440\u043e\u0438\u0442\u0435\u043b\u044c\u0441\u0442\u0432\u043e","count":"4516"}]
```

Comment: I'm getting 404 while trying to access the URL..

Comment: Since you are getting an error, why don't you log the error data so you know exactly what error you are getting.

Comment: Have u tried watching in the browser developer tools? If you're using chrome hit that exact url and/or see in the "network" panel to see whether the remote address is being reached.

Comment: When I try to hit your url, I get a 404 too. Perhaps the url has some access control mechanism based on IP and you're deploying the front-end in a non-trusted host?

Comment: http://yuppi.com.ua/rest/categories.php?key=453sdfg3t, I changed URL

Comment: instead using the URL with an explicit query string, pass the query string params to the second object: $http.get('http://.../categories.php', {params: {key: "453sdfg3t"}})

Comment: No, this is my host, and I can reach it from current network. There is no filters inside server.

Comment: try separating the querystring as I told in the last comment

Comment: $http.get('http://yuppi.com.ua/rest/categories.php', {params: {key: "453sdfg3t"}})
       .success(function(){
           alert("sfasdfad"); and success alert still not shown
       });

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61297/discussion-between-user1315599-and-luis-masuelli).

Answer (score 1):

Quite clearly, you're hitting the error function because the response from that URL doesn't contain the CORS headers to enable your browser to qualify the request as *allowed*.

You can see the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/frbrn32d/

And you can read up on cross domain requests to understand better what is happening. Moreover, to solve problems like these, it is best to make changes to the API to send the appropriate headers. It is possible to temporarily disable the browser specific CORS security checks, but that is not a solution.

Here's the test code;

```
var app = angular.module("TestApp", []);

app.controller("TestCtrl", ["$http", "$scope", function($http, $scope) {
    $scope.msg = "Hello, world!";
    $http.get("http://yuppi.com.ua/rest/categories.php?key=453sdfg3t")
    .success(function (response) {
        console.log("RESPONSE", response);
    })
    .error(function (err, status, headers) {
        console.error("ERR", err, status);
    });
}]);
```

When you fire up the javascript console, you'll see the error messages.

Comment: so.. as I understand CORS, if I will move my resources (HTML, js files) to the same server -  I will not have problems with CORS?

Comment: @user1315599 You needn't host the frontend and the backend on the same machine – what matters is that in your responses from the backend, the right headers are sent so that the browser receiving the response knows that it is allowed by the server to receive data from the server. You can either set the headers on the server to *, which will allow the responses from the server to be read anywhere, or you can allow it for a specific address range, or for a specific address itself. This address will be the same address from which your front end is hosted.

Comment: For now, I am using godaddy providers and there is not way to modify configuration for Apache. I found that this  header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); should help to set correct header.

Comment: I believe you're using PHP to serve requests? I think adding this to your PHP script serving that request should suffice: `header("access-control-allow-origin: *")`. PHP works a bit funny so sometimes you might want to add that line before you write anything to PHP's output buffer – it'll throw errors otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

If you have CORS issue add this header to the php file `header("access-control-allow-origin: *");`

Comment: I added this to header and still see error in console DOMException [NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI: "Access to restricted URI denied"
code: 1012
nsresult: 0x805303f4
location: file:///C:/Users/hffff/Desktop/Angular/js/vendor/angular.min.js:83]

Comment: Make sure that you are running the project from your localhost?